# How to correctly generate a transaction sequence number for a private Stellar network?

Tags: go-sdk

I am using a private Stellar network with Horizon but struggling to get the first accounts created using the Go SDK. When attempting to create an account using the autosequence option with the client I have created I get the following error:

> mutator:1 failed: couldn't load account for auto sequence: load account failed.

Here is the code:

```
c := &horizon.Client{
        URL:  "my horizon url",
        HTTP: http.DefaultClient,
    }

    // Root secret
    seed := "my network root secret key"

    acc, _ := keypair.Random()
    pubkey := acc.Address()

    tx, err := b.Transaction(
        b.SourceAccount{seed},
        b.AutoSequence{SequenceProvider: c},
        b.Network{"My network passphrase"},
        b.CreateAccount(
            b.Destination{pubkey},
            b.NativeAmount{"50"},
        ),
    )
```

I have also tried setting the sequence number using b.Sequence to zero and one and get the following error for that:

> Horizon error: "Transaction Failed".

When I check the transaction result codes I see "tx_bad_seq". I think autosequence is the way to go but would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction when using this with a private network.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading from Horizon 0.15.2 to 0.16 seems to have resolved this. The transaction auto sequence now works.